# Iframes with browser

Tags: javascript

I have two `Iframes` and two `dropdown` list for each of the iframes.

Dropdown contains browser names like `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE`, etc.

Now what I want is: whenever I am selecting a browser from the dropdown, it should get load into that particular iframe.

I tried this with `Webdrivers` but the problem I am facing is that its opening in the new window. I tried with `window.open` command and facing the same problem. I used the `div` tag as the alternative for iframes but i am getting the same problem. How to deal with this??

Comment: Firstly, you tagged this with Java, but this sounds more like you're talking about Javascript. Second, it is far easier to help with your problem if you post the relevant code and indicate where you seem to be having difficulty.

Comment: Edit your question to add a snippet of what you tried.

Comment: Please add the snippet that you have tried